# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the query I have written

```
DECLARE @entityName VARCHAR(20) = 'Job'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @userId INT = 4

SET @sql = 'select v.Id,[Title], [HiringCompany], [EmploymentType], 
                   [Status], [Priority], [ExperienceLevel], [Salary], 
                   [Location], [AssignedRecruiter], 
                   [PipelineCount], [CreationDate],
                   [Department], [PublishingStatus], 
                   CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsFavourite 
             from JobListView v 
             left join (select * from Favourite 
                        where EntityType = '''+ @entityName +''' 
                          and IsDeleted = 0 and userId = '+ @userId +') f on v.Id = f.EntityId';

EXEC (@sql)
```

This is the exception I am getting:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select v.Id,[Title], 
>       [HiringCompany], [EmploymentType], [Status], [Priority], 
>       [ExperienceLevel], [Salary], [Location], [AssignedRecruiter], 
>       [PipelineCount], [CreationDate],
>       [Department], [PublishingStatus], CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 
>       IsFavourite from
>       JobListView v Left join (select * from Favourite where EntityType = 'Job' 
>       and IsDeleted = 0 and userId = ' to data type int.

May I know what I have missed in my query?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql in the first place? From what you posted there is no reason at all for dynamic sql. This looks like it should just be a parameterized query.

Comment: I didn't post the complete query I am passing dynamic column names that's why I am using  dynamic SQL otherwise it is not needed as you said

Answer (score 3):

Learn to use parameters using `sp_executesql`!

```
set @sql = '
select v.Id,[Title], [HiringCompany], [EmploymentType], [Status], [Priority], 
      [ExperienceLevel], [Salary], [Location], [AssignedRecruiter], 
      [PipelineCount], [CreationDate],
      [Department], [PublishingStatus], CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 
IsFavourite
from JobListView v Left join
     (select *
      from Favourite
      where EntityType = @entityName and
            IsDeleted = 0 and
            userId = @userId
     ) f
     on v.Id = f.EntityId';

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@entityName varchar(20), @userId int', 
                   @entityName=@entityName, @userId=@userId;
```

You also don't need the subquery for the `left join`.  I left it in, but the filtering conditions can go in the outer `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to be using dynamic sql in the first place. It is just adding a layer of unnecessary complexity. Here is your code without the dynamic sql.

```
Declare @entityName VARCHAR(20) = 'Job'
    , @userId INT = 4

select v.Id
    ,Title
    , HiringCompany
    , EmploymentType
    , Status
    , Priority
    , ExperienceLevel
    , Salary
    , Location
    , AssignedRecruiter
    , PipelineCount
    , CreationDate
    , Department
    , PublishingStatus
    , CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsFavourite 
from JobListView v 
Left join 
(
    select * 
    from Favourite 
    where EntityType = @entityName 
        and IsDeleted = 0 and userId = @userId
) f on v.Id = f.EntityId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CAST`:

```
Declare @entityName VARCHAR(20) = 'Job'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @userId INT = 4;
SET @sql = 'select v.Id,[Title], [HiringCompany], [EmploymentType], 
[Status], 
[Priority], 
[ExperienceLevel], [Salary], [Location], [AssignedRecruiter], 
[PipelineCount], [CreationDate],
[Department], [PublishingStatus], CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 
IsFavourite from  
JobListView v Left join (select * from Favourite where EntityType = '''+ 
@entityName +''' 
and IsDeleted = 0 and userId = '+ CAST(@userId  AS VARCHAR(10))+') f on v.Id = f.EntityId';
                                 -- here

EXEC (@sql);
```

---

Proper way is using sp_executesql:

```
Declare @entityName VARCHAR(20) = 'Job'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @userId INT = 4
SET @sql = 'select v.Id,[Title], [HiringCompany], [EmploymentType], 
[Status], 
[Priority], 
[ExperienceLevel], [Salary], [Location], [AssignedRecruiter], 
[PipelineCount], [CreationDate],
[Department], [PublishingStatus], CASE WHEN f.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 
IsFavourite from  
JobListView v Left join (select * from Favourite where EntityType = @EntityName  
and IsDeleted = 0 and userId = @userId) f on v.Id = f.EntityId';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@EntityName VARCHAR(20), @userId INT',
                   @EntityName, @userId;
```